# How to create a generic route?

Tags: symfony, dynamic, routes

I am working with a Symfony2 project and I would like to create a generic route,
my achievement is write something like www.mysite.com/myController/myAction and redirect automatically
to

```
class myControllerController {
 public function myActionAction()  {   }
}
```

in my file routing.yml I wrote that

```
api:
  pattern:   /{_controller}/{_action} 
  defaults: {_bundle: LetsbuyBundle, _controller: LetsbuyBundle:{_controller}, _action:{_action}  }
```

but it doesn't work

error message is:

> "Unable to parse the controller name "myController"."

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited the title for you but please remember to turn off your caps the next time you post :)

Answer (score 0):

For that url, you would need to name your controller myControllerController.

Comment: sorry I wrote wrongly mny example... my controller follow the right naming convention ad  you has suggested :-)